# XDM software starting up on login but not present in Login items

Tags: catalina, login-items

I am using [XDM (Xtreme Download Manager software)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/) on my Mac.

When I login then the XDM software is started. But I do not see it in Login items(System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Items tab.)

How is the software starting up if it is not present in Login items and How do I stop it from opening automatically on Login?

[image: XDM started on MAC login]

[image: XDM not present in MAC login items]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/969387/mac-os-x-disable-program-on-startup-that-is-not-listed-in-accounts-login-ite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to change the settings below in the XDM application (Tools -> Options-> Advanced settings -> View settings.)

I used homebrew to install XDM and this option is selected by default.

[image]

If you look at the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/xdman/code/ci/master/tree/xdman/util/MacUtils.java) you'll find that the automatic start is controlled by a LaunchAgent called `org.sdg.xdman.plist` stored in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`.

```
public static void addToStartup() {
  File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Library/LaunchAgents");
  dir.mkdirs();
  File f = new File(dir, "org.sdg.xdman.plist");
  FileOutputStream fs = null;
  ...
```

Comment: @nohillside: I dont see `org.sdg.xdman.plist` file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` in my MAC

Comment: It gets removed if you untick the checkbox :-)